# How to create a dialog using string for multiple languages

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to create a dialog on Android studio that displays an error message in different languages.
Currently, I have just one error message (in German):

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Error message + error description
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Keine Internetverbindung verfügbar: " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

I think I need to create arrays and add the same message in other languages, the problem is I didn't figure out yet how to do it.

Comment: Assuming your Application uses the system-language, have a look at [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Hi didn't you try this ?

Comment: It worked like @ShreeKrishna said.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are still having some issue then I am ready to help else please feel free to accept the answer. I will be pleased...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as you've previously stated before, you can create an array list of different languages your app will support (maybe have an options menu for selection) and then at the spots where you hardcoded your text (Ex. "Keine Internetverbindung verfügbar: ") replace that with another parameter in the method.

In terms of the array you could use, depending on how large and organized you want your program, you can make different ArrayList objects for each language. What I would recommend is making a HashMap of all phrases in your program and organize them in such a way HashMap where the first string would be something like "germanIntro" and the second String would be "Keine Internetverbindung verfügbar: ".

In order to learn more about how to use an ArrayList or HashMap , I'd recommend just googling or looking at other stack overflow answers.

EDIT: I'm sure auto translators are available to use somehow (I've never tried) but I know they aren't 100% accurate. That being said, if you do know the language, I'd recommend hardcoding the correct phrases.

Answer (score 0):

**No you don't need,
Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) about localization,**

You create one `/values/strings.xml` for universal approach

and you have to create `/values-de/strings.xml` for german language.

**Then after your `/values/strings.xml` will look like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="message">No internet connection available</string>
</resources>
```

**And your `/values-de/strings.xml` will look like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="message">Keine Internetverbindung verfügbar</string>
</resources>
```

**Then you can show the dialog as per localized String**

```
void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Error message + error description
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, getString(R.string.message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```